# Express-generator application not found by command prompt

Tags: express-generator

I installed express-generator but when I write in CMD (express --view=ejs astronomy) it gives me this error: 'express' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I did with express-generator couple projects before I installed anaconda python 3.7.4

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not installed `express` globally!

to install it globally, try the following.

`npm install -g express`

Also, if express is not in your PATH you have to add the full path to run it in `cmd`:

`\myproject\node_modules\.bin\express.cmd`

(Usually *is not recognized as an internal or external command* happens because the system couldn't find it in the path variable!)